# Order By Error in SQL Statement

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have the following SQL statement

```
   sql = "SELECT DISTINCT " & _
    "'<option value=""' + CAST([alpha] AS VARCHAR) + '"">' + " & _
     "[alpha] + '</option>' " & _
     "FROM scheme.podetm LEFT OUTER JOIN scheme.poheadm ON scheme.podetm.order_no =scheme.poheadm.order_no WHERE scheme.podetm.product= '"& partnumber & "' Order By [alpha]"
```

I am getting the error

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14'

ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

line 374

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
Order By [alpha]
```

in the end of this query you must write

```
Order by '<option value=""' + CAST([alpha] AS VARCHAR) + '"">' + [alpha] + '</option>'
```